# Plone 4.2.4 (4210) / Diazo theme "Beyondskins Responsive": Password reset issue

Tags: passwords, plone, reset, rules, diazo

Since I'm using the "Beyondskins responsive" Diazo theme, I'm not able to
use the Password reset feature.
Users received the Pasword reset e-mail. Plone asks them for a new password
and then it fails with the following message:

> /Error setting password Sorry, this appears to be an invalid request.
>   Please make sure you copied the URL exactly as it appears in your
>   email and that you entered your user name correctly. /

Maybe a rules.xml issue?

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is broken because the released version of beyondskins.responsive is missing a rule to copy the base tag from the head of the content. There is an unreleased fix in the beyondskins.responsive github repository.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I tried with the rules.xml and index.html from Github and it works OK.

Thanks again, the issue was make me going crazy.

Regards